# Difference between $(Rev:r) and $(Rev:.r) in BuildNumber part of Azure DevOps Build Pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, build-pipeline

Was going through this doc [Configure run or build numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and found usage of both $(Rev:r) and $(Rev:.r) but no definition .r one.

Do anyone know difference between the two ?

Also checked a community issue [Description of $(Rev:r) lacks meaning of $(Rev:.r) and its used on this page in most of examples](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/11941) raised regarding same, but did not find anysolution there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is just having or not having an extra dot (**`.`**) character to the build number.

For example:

- If setting the build number the as **`$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)`**, the result will look like **`20231017.1`**.
- If setting the build number the as **`$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:r)`**, the result will look like **`202310171`**.